# How to query products without weight in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, sql

I have been able to SQL query my products that have weight in Magento 2

`select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id=80 and value is not null`

However, when I try to look up products without weight "value is null" I get none. Is there a way to look up which products don't have weight added to them via SQL or admin panel?

Comment: you means get product collection without weight using sql query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL is case sensitive. The correct SQL query for getting attribute_id=80 and value is NULL would be:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id=80 and value is NULL;
```

Please note that the attribute_id will differ between Magento installations and can be found with:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code LIKE '%weight%';
```

This will not give you what you want as the attribute_id will not exist in the catalog_product_entity_decimal-table if the product is not having a weight set.

One easy way to get products without weight is through the admin-panel.

1. Go into your product-catalog, through Catalog ==> Products.
2. Press on Columns (cog-wheel icon, on the top left corner of the product table).
3. Select to show weight and sort on the weight-column.

Comment: Precisely. The answer I was after.  Thank you.